# How do I insert a row which contains a foreign key?

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key, postgresql-9.1, insert

Using PostgreSQL v9.1.  I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE foo
(
    id BIGSERIAL     NOT NULL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
    type VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE bar
(
    id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
    description VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    foo_id BIGINT NOT NULL REFERENCES foo ON DELETE RESTRICT
);
```

Say the first table `foo` is populated like this:

```
INSERT INTO foo (type) VALUES
    ( 'red' ),
    ( 'green' ),
    ( 'blue' );
```

Is there any way to insert rows into `bar` easily by referencing the `foo` table?  Or must I do it in two steps, first by looking up the `foo` type I want, and then inserting a new row into `bar`?

Here is an example of pseudo-code showing what I was hoping could be done:

```
INSERT INTO bar (description, foo_id) VALUES
    ( 'testing',     SELECT id from foo WHERE type='blue' ),
    ( 'another row', SELECT id from foo WHERE type='red'  );
```

Comment: This is a nicely worded question that is exactly what I'm looking for, thank you for the post

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Your syntax is almost good, needs some parenthesis around the subqueries and it will work:

```
INSERT INTO bar (description, foo_id) VALUES
    ( 'testing',     (SELECT id from foo WHERE type='blue') ),
    ( 'another row', (SELECT id from foo WHERE type='red' ) );
```

Tested at [DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/krZer5MqK3y9j5Jvn7giLE/0)

Another way, with shorter syntax if you have a lot of values to insert:

```
WITH ins (description, type) AS
( VALUES
    ( 'more testing',   'blue') ,
    ( 'yet another row', 'green' )
)  
INSERT INTO bar
   (description, foo_id) 
SELECT 
    ins.description, foo.id
FROM 
  foo JOIN ins
    ON ins.type = foo.type ;
```

Comment: Took reading it a few times, but I now understand that 2nd solution you provided.  I like it.  Using it now to bootstrap my database with a handful of known values when the system first comes up.

Comment: why do you say 'if you have lot of inserts' for 2nd? Is it faster or just easier to write you mean?

Comment: Compare the 1st and 2nd method if you have 100 rows to insert. 2nd will be shorter.

Answer (score 57):

#### Plain `INSERT`

```
INSERT INTO bar (description, foo_id)
SELECT val.description, f.id
FROM  (
   VALUES
      (text 'testing', text 'blue')  -- explicit type declaration; see below
    , ('another row' , 'red' )
    , ('new row1'    , 'purple')      -- purple does not exist in foo, yet
    , ('new row2'    , 'purple')
   ) val (description, type)
LEFT   JOIN foo f USING (type);
```

- `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` instead of `[INNER] JOIN` means that rows from `val` **all rows are kept**, even when no match is found in `foo`. Instead, `NULL` is entered for `foo_id` (which raises an exception if the column is defined `NOT NULL`).
- The `VALUES` expression in the subquery does the same as [@ypercube's](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/46415/3684) CTE. [Common Table Expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) offer additional features and are easier to read in big queries, but they also pose as optimization barriers (up to Postgres 12). Subqueries are typically a bit faster when none of the above is needed.
- You may need explicit type casts. Since the `VALUES` expression is not directly attached to a table (like in `INSERT ... VALUES ...`), types cannot be derived and default data types are used unless typed explicitly. This may not work in all cases. It's enough to do it in the first row, the rest falls in line.

#### `INSERT` missing FK rows at the same time

To create missing entries in `foo` on the fly, in a *single SQL statement*, CTEs are instrumental:

```sql
WITH sel AS (
   SELECT val.description, val.type, f.id AS foo_id
   FROM  (
      VALUES
         (text 'testing', text 'blue')
       , ('another row', 'red'   )
       , ('new row1'   , 'purple')
       , ('new row2'   , 'purple')
      ) val (description, type)
   LEFT   JOIN foo f USING (type)
   )
, ins AS ( 
   INSERT INTO foo (type)
   SELECT DISTINCT type FROM sel WHERE foo_id IS NULL
   RETURNING id AS foo_id, type
   )
INSERT INTO bar (description, foo_id)
SELECT sel.description, COALESCE(sel.foo_id, ins.foo_id)
FROM   sel
LEFT   JOIN ins USING (type);
```

Old [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e09d6/1) for Postgres 9.6 - works the same in 9.1. Also see new fiddle below!

Note the two additional rows to insert. Both are *purple*, which does not exist in `foo`, yet. *Two* rows to illustrate the need for `DISTINCT` in the first `INSERT` statement.

#### Step-by-step explanation

1. The 1st CTE `sel` provides multiple rows of input data. The subquery `val` with the `VALUES` expression can be replaced with a table or subquery as source. Immediately `LEFT JOIN` to `foo` to append the `foo_id` for pre-existing `type` rows. All other rows get `foo_id IS NULL` this way.
2. The 2nd CTE `ins` inserts *distinct* new types (`foo_id IS NULL`) into `foo`, and returns the newly generated `foo_id` - together with the `type` to join back to insert rows.
3. The final outer `INSERT` can now insert a `foo_id` for every row: either the type pre-existed, or it was inserted in step 2.

Strictly speaking, both inserts happen "in parallel", but since this is a *single* statement, default `FOREIGN KEY` constraints will not complain. Referential integrity is enforced at the end of the statement by default.

There is a tiny **race condition** if you run multiple of these queries concurrently. See:

- [Atomic UPDATE .. SELECT in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11532550/939860)
- [Is SELECT or INSERT in a function prone to race conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15950324/939860)
- [How do I implement insert-if-not-found for transactions at serializable isolation level?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/26905/how-do-i-implement-insert-if-not-found-for-transactions-at-serializable-isolatio/26909#26909)

Really only happens under heavy concurrent load, if ever. In comparison to caching solutions like advertised in another answer, the chance is *super-tiny*.

#### Function for repeated use

Create an SQL function that takes an array of composite type as parameter and use `unnest(param)` in place of the `VALUES` expression.

Or, if the syntax for such an array seems too messy, use a comma-separated string as parameter `_param`. For instance of the form:

```
'description1,type1;description2,type2;description3,type3'
```

Then use this to replace the `VALUES` expression in above statement:

```
SELECT split_part(x, ',', 1) AS description
       split_part(x, ',', 2) AS type
FROM   unnest(string_to_array(_param, ';')) x;
```

## Function with UPSERT in Postgres 9.5 or later

Create a custom row type for parameter passing. We could do without it, but it's simpler:

```
CREATE TYPE foobar AS (description text, type text);
```

Function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_insert_foobar(VARIADIC _val foobar[])
  RETURNS void
  LANGUAGE sql AS
$func$
WITH val AS (SELECT * FROM unnest(_val))    -- well-known row type
,    typ AS (
   SELECT v.type, f.id                      -- id NOT NULL where type already exists
   FROM  (SELECT DISTINCT type FROM val) v  -- DISTINCT!
   LEFT   JOIN foo f USING (type)           -- assuming no concurrent update/delete on foo
                                            -- else you might lock rows here.
   )
,    ins AS ( 
   INSERT INTO foo AS f (type)
   SELECT type
   FROM   typ
   WHERE  id IS NULL
   ON     CONFLICT (type) DO UPDATE         -- RARE cases of concurrent inserts
   SET    type = EXCLUDED.type              -- overwrite to make visible
   RETURNING f.type, f.id
   )
INSERT INTO bar AS b (description, foo_id)
SELECT v.description, COALESCE(t.id, i.id)  -- assuming most types pre-exist
FROM        val v
LEFT   JOIN typ t USING (type)              -- already existed
LEFT   JOIN ins i USING (type)              -- newly inserted
ON     CONFLICT (description) DO UPDATE     -- description already exists
SET    foo_id = EXCLUDED.foo_id             -- real UPSERT this time
WHERE  b.foo_id <> EXCLUDED.foo_id;         -- only if actually changed
$func$;
```

Call:

```sql
SELECT f_insert_foobar(
     '(testing,blue)'
   , '(another row,red)'
   , '(new row1,purple)'
   , '(new row2,green)'
   , '("with,comma",green)'  -- added to demonstrate row syntax
   );
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5d1c14e2f06982bcbb7697fe44de1cf2)*

Fast and rock-solid for environments with concurrent transactions.

In addition to the queries above, this function ...

- ... applies `SELECT` or `INSERT` on `foo`: Any `type` that doesn't exist in the FK table, yet, is inserted. Assuming most types pre-exist.
- ... applies `INSERT` or `UPDATE` (true "UPSERT") on `bar`: If the `description` already exists, its `type` is updated - but only if it actually changes. See:

  - [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12632129/939860)
- ... passes values as well-known row types with a `VARIADIC` function parameter. Note the default maximum of 100 function parameters! See:

  - [Select rows such that names match elements of input array for pgsql function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17978831/939860)

  There are many other ways to pass multiple rows ...

Related:

- [How to use RETURNING with ON CONFLICT in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42217872/939860)
- [How to include excluded rows in RETURNING from INSERT ... ON CONFLICT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35953488/939860)

Comment: In your `INSERT missing FK rows at the same time` example, would putting this in a Transaction reduce the risk of race conditions in SQL Server?

Comment: @element11: The answer is for Postgres, but since we are talking about a *single* SQL command, it's a single transaction in any case. Executing it inside a bigger transaction would only *increase* the time window for possible race conditions. As for SQL Server: data-modifying CTEs are not supported at all (only `SELECT` inside a `WITH` clause) . [Source: MS documentation.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)

Comment: You can also do this with `INSERT ... RETURNING \gset` in `psql` then use the returned values as psql `:'variables'`, but this only works for single row inserts.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter this is great, but I'm too new to sql to understand it all, could you add some comments to "INSERT missing FK rows at the same time" explaining how it works? also, thanks for the SQLFiddle working examples!

Comment: @glallen: I added a step-by-step explanation. There are also many links to related answers and the manual with more explanation. You *need* to understand what the query does or you may be in over your head.

Comment: Bravo on the single statement. I understand that MySQL won't support CTEs until 8.0, would this single statement be feasible in MySQL without CTEs?

Comment: @Jon: I don't think so. But please ask your new question as *question*. You can always link to this one for context.

Comment: Brilliant explanation and examples!

Comment: Good job, @ErwinBrandstetter! A tiny question, what if the to-insert values are NULL but it's not in string type which means we have to explicitly cast their data types? I couldn't come up with another solution other than do `CAST(col AS target_data_type) while inserting?

Comment: @MemphisMeng: It depends. My function `f_insert_foo_bar()` works with well-defined input type, so explicit casting is not required for untyped string  literals. Typed input is also coerced automatically *if* at least an assignment cast is defined. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12427434/939860 If anything is still unclear, consider a new question with relevant details for your case.

Answer (score 6):

Lookup. You basically need the foo id's to insert them into bar.

Not postgres specific, btw. (and you did not tag it like that) - this is generally how SQL works. No shortcuts here.

Application wise, though, you may have a cache of foo items in memory. My tables often have up to 3 unique fields:

- Id (integer or something) that is the table level primary key.
- Identifier, which is a GUID that is used as stable ID application level wise (and may be exposed to the customer in URL's etc.)
- Code - a string that may be there and has to be unique if it is there (sql server: filtered unique index on not null). That is a customer set identifier.

Example:

- Account (in a trading application)
  -> Id is a int used for foreign keys.
  -> Identifier is a Guid and used in the web portals etc. - always accepted.
  -> Code is manually set. Rule: once set it does not change.

Obviously when you want to link something to an account - you first must, technically, get the Id - but given both Identifier and Code never change once they are there, a positive cache in memory kan stop most lookups from hitting the database.

Comment: You are aware that you can let the RDBMS do the lookup for you, in a single SQL statement, avoiding error-prone cache?

Comment: You are aware that looking up non-changing elements is not error prone? Also, typically, the RDBMS is not scalable and the most expensive element in the game, due to licensing costs. Taking as much load from it as possible is not exactly bad. Also, not many ORM's do support that to start with.

Comment: Non-changing elements? Most expensive element? Licensing costs (for PostgreSQL)? ORMs defining what's sane? No I wasn't aware of all of that.

Comment: Hi! Learning SQL. So even though every entry has a unique ID, you would still need other unique fields to help with lookups on the db is what you're saying? I looked at other solutions on this page and was wondering this. Your response is at the bottom but seems to confirm that.

Comment: "Non-changing elements?" - yeah, an account i.e. is non changing. "Licensing costs (for PostgreSQL)?" - yeah, better learn it in a way that gets you laughed at when you work with high end databases like Oracle. After all, it is a virtue to be non professional. " ORMs defining what's sane?" - no, orm's defining what is common. Sane is another thing, but many ORM's are hardly allowing all features. And given that the ORM reduces development cost by about 40% NOT caring for it is insane. But then, on your world money seems to grow on trees.