# Insert New Foreign Key Row for new Strings

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, foreign-key, cte

Lets say I have a table `new_data` like this:

```
ndx    | someval | somemachine
serial | integer | integer
----------------------------
```

And let's say I have a reference table `new_data_someval_ref`:

```
someval | someval_str
integer | varchar
---------------------
```

(Where, obviously, new_data_someval_ref.someval is foreign key on new_data.someval)

And I want do inserts like so:

```
INSERT INTO new_data
  (someval, machine)
VALUES (
  (SELECT someval
   FROM new_data_someval_ref
   WHERE someval_str = ?),
  ?)
```

BUT, if there is no match in the reference table, I would like to add a row containing the new string and an incremented `someval`, then do the insert above.

So my question is there clean, possibly even constraint-based way to do this?

(I use both Postgres and SQL Server regularly, so an answer addressing both would be ideal, but not necessary.)

Comment: Just add the referenced value in the same transaction?  Also, your example is not very clear.  We don't know what sort of type `someval_str` is, but it is certainly not an integer.  Probably some actual `CREATE TABLE` statements would help.

Comment: It's labeled as a varchar in the second table block

Comment: Yeah, that's true.  What this shows is that a `CREATE TABLE` would be much more understandable...

Comment: "Obviously"? It seems to be the other way round: `new_data.someval` is a foreign key on `new_data_someval_ref.someval`. To avoid such ambiguities, it is ***always*** better to provide complete `CREATE TABLE` scripts.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `someval` is actually an auto-generated column like a [`serial`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL).

In Postgres this [**data-modifying CTE**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) (writeable CTE) would do the job:

```
WITH sel AS (
   SELECT r.someval, i.someval_str, i.machine
   FROM  (SELECT ?, ?) AS i(someval_str, machine)
   LEFT   JOIN new_data_someval_ref r USING (someval_str)
   )
, ins AS ( 
   INSERT INTO new_data_someval_ref (someval_str)
   SELECT DISTINCT someval_str FROM sel WHERE someval IS NULL
   RETURNING someval, someval_str
   )
INSERT INTO new_data (someval, machine)
SELECT COALESCE(sel.someval, ins.someval), sel.machine
FROM   sel
LEFT   JOIN ins USING (someval_str);
```

Everything standard SQL, not sure whether it's all implemented in SQL Server identically.

For a query with multiple input rows and ample explanation:

- [How do I insert a row which contains a foreign key?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46410/how-do-i-insert-a-row-which-contains-a-foreign-key/46477#46477)

There is a *tiny* chance for a **race condition** under heavy concurrent load. (Doing everything in a single statement minimizes the time window.) If that's the case:

- [Is SELECT or INSERT in a function prone to race conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939902/is-select-or-insert-in-a-function-prone-to-race-conditions/15950324#15950324)

Answer (score 1):

I think you will have to break it into 2 blocks (stored procedure would be easier)

```
DECLARE @SomeVal INT 

SET @SomeVal = Isnull((SELECT someval 
                       FROM   new_data_someval_ref 
                       WHERE  someval_str = 'WhatEverTheValueIs'), 0) 

IF @SomeVal = 0 
  BEGIN 
      INSERT INTO new_data_someval_ref 
                  (someval_str) 
      VALUES      ('WhatEverTheValueIs') 

      SET @SomeVal = Scope_identity() 
  END 

INSERT INTO new_data
                 (someval, machine) 
VALUES           (@SomeVal, ?)
```