# postgresql Insert into table B based on foreign key in table A, if exists in A else

Tags: postgresql

the scenario is as follows:

I have an `invoice` and `supplier` table. The `invoice` references `supplier` on `supplier_id`. I want to insert into `invoice`. If `supplier_company` does not exist in the `supplier` table, first insert into `supplier` then use the new `supplier_id` in `invoice`, else use the `supplier_id` of the matching `supplier_name`.

I've managed to get here:

`insert into supplier (supplier_company) select ('Company Name') where not exists (select 1 from supplier where supplier_company='Company Name');

insert into invoice (invoice_number, supplier_id) values (xxx, (select supplier_id from supplier where supplier_company = 'Company Name')`

but I was wondering if there's a cleaner, clearer way to express this in one expression.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I think this answer to a very similar question is quite elegant: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46410/how-do-i-insert-a-row-which-contains-a-foreign-key/46477#46477 Note: not my answer there but Erwin's (the code under the **INSERT missing FK rows at the same time** title).

Comment: A single statement can change at most one table. So it is impossible for one expression to insert rows into two tables.

Comment: @ypercube I agree, it does what I'm looking for well, thank you!

Comment: @Andomar in Postgres, you can insert into / update / delete from 2 (or more) tables in one statement, using CTEs.