# Deduplicate SELECT statements in relational division

Tags: redshift, relational-division

I have a query that does a lot of duplicate work:

```
SELECT visitor_id, '1'::text AS filter    
FROM events    
WHERE id IN (SELECT event_id FROM params
             WHERE key = 'utm_campaign' AND value = 'campaign_one')
  AND id IN (SELECT event_id FROM params
             WHERE key = 'utm_source'   AND value = 'facebook')
GROUP BY visitor_id

UNION ALL

SELECT visitor_id, '2'::text AS filter
FROM events    
WHERE id IN (SELECT event_id FROM params
             WHERE key = 'utm_campaign' AND value = 'campaign_two')
  AND id IN (SELECT event_id FROM params
             WHERE key = 'utm_source'   AND value = 'facebook')
GROUP BY visitor_id
```

As you can see, it performs different filtering on the params table 4 times. I'm using Redshift and although it scans this table very quickly, I have quite a few of these statements `UNION`ed together. Is there a way to rewrite the SQL using `CASE`/`IF` statements?

The example uses `key = 'utm_source' AND value = 'facebook'` in both, but this is not necessarily true for all selects.

Answer (score 3):

I see a possible minor simplification with a CTE ([available in Redshift](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WITH_clause.html)) for the repeated subquery with identical predicates:

```
WITH p2 AS (
   SELECT event_id
   FROM   params 
   WHERE  key = 'utm_source' AND value = 'facebook'
   )
SELECT e.visitor_id, '1'::text AS filter   
FROM          p2 
JOIN   params p1 USING (event_id)
JOIN   events e ON e.id = p2.event_id
WHERE  p1.key = 'utm_campaign' AND p1.value = 'campaign_one'
GROUP  BY e.visitor_id

UNION ALL
SELECT e.visitor_id, '2'::text AS filter   
FROM          p2 
JOIN   params p1 USING (event_id)
JOIN   events e ON e.id = p2.event_id
WHERE  p1.key = 'utm_campaign' AND p1.value = 'campaign_two'
GROUP  BY e.visitor_id;
```

Plain joins may also be faster than multiple `IN` semi-joins.

This multicolumn index should allow [index-only scans](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans) on `params`:

```
CREATE INDEX foo_idx ON params (key, value, event_id)
```

Add another index on just `(event_id)` if you don't have one, yet.

Arsenal of available query techniques for relational division under this related question on SO:

- [How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7364969/939860)

#### Avoid multiple SELECTs

As [commented by @Andriy](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/111345/how-to-deduplicate-select-statements-in-relational-division/111362?noredirect=1#comment202327_111362), we can squeeze out some more:

```
WITH p2 AS (  -- repeated, immutable filter
   SELECT event_id
   FROM   params 
   WHERE  key = 'utm_source' AND value = 'facebook'
   )
, p3 (value, filter) AS (  -- values for variable filter
   SELECT text 'campaign_one', text '1'
   UNION ALL SELECT 'campaign_two', '2'
   )
SELECT e.visitor_id, p3.filter   
FROM          p3
JOIN   params p1 USING (value)
JOIN          p2 USING (event_id)
JOIN   events e ON e.id = p2.event_id
WHERE  p1.key = 'utm_campaign'  -- repeated for p1
GROUP  BY 1, 2;
```

In Postgres we could use a shorter, faster `VALUES` expression, but that feature is [not currently supported in Redshift](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-features.html):

```
...
, p3 (value, filter) AS (
     VALUES
     (text 'campaign_one', text '1')
   , (     'campaign_two',      '2')
   )
...
```

For just two `SELECT` in the `UNION`, this won't buy much. But it should be a substantial improvement for more - like you mentioned.

#### 2nd query without CTE

The CTE is not *necessary* for the second query. You can simplify to:

```
SELECT e.visitor_id, p3.filter   
FROM  (
   SELECT text 'campaign_one' AS value, text '1' AS filter
   UNION ALL SELECT 'campaign_two', '2'
   ) p3                            -- values for variable filter
JOIN   params p1 USING (value)
JOIN   params p2 USING (event_id)
JOIN   events e ON e.id = p2.event_id
WHERE  p1.key = 'utm_campaign'     -- repeated, immutable filters
AND    p2.key = 'utm_source'
AND    p2.value = 'facebook'
GROUP  BY 1, 2;
```

#### About CTEs

Resources for Common Table Expressions (as requested in the comment):

- [The manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html)
- [Tag info for CTE.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/cte/info)

[Data-modifying CTEs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) are particularly useful. Example:

- [How do I insert a row which contains a foreign key?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46410/how-do-i-insert-a-row-which-contains-a-foreign-key/46477#46477)

Basics with an added advanced example on this related answer on SO:

- [Are SELECT type queries the only type that can be nested?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22750328/939860)