# how to select a value in one table with max() to update a row in a second table, with a trigger in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, trigger

Here is **tbl1** :

```
gid pm
1   2.1
2   2.0
3   1.95
...
```

Here is **tbl2** I want :

```
gid num pb  gidTbl1
1    1        1
2    2        1
3    3  2.1   1
4    1        2
5    2        2
6    3        2
7    4  2.0   2
8    1        3
...
```

On an insert in tbl2, I would like that pb = pm for gidTbl1 = gid **AND** for the max num in tbl2.
Here are a trigger and the function on tbl2 I wrote :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION maj_pb()
RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
COST 100
VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF
AS $BODY$
begin
IF TG_OP IN ('INSERT')
THEN NEW.pb = pm from tbl1
        where NEW.gidTbl1 = tbl1.gid
        and num = (select max(num) from tbl2
                          where NEW.gidTbl1 = g.gid
                        ) ;
RETURN NEW ;
END IF ;
END ;
$BODY$;

CREATE TRIGGER trg_maj_pb
BEFORE INSERT
ON tbl2
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE activite.maj_pb();
```

- error message is :

> num doesn't exist

I presume that the trigger is looking for `num` in tbl1 (?). But I can't find an other way to write the function.

- I add : In fact, whatever I do (insert or update) the max `num` by gidTbl1 (tbl2) always has to have the `pm` corresponding in tbl1.

Answer (score 1):

The immediate error is that you have `num` where it would have to be `NEW.num`. But there are more problems ...

> I add : In fact, whatever I do (insert or update) the max `num` by gidTbl1 (tbl2) always has to have the `pm` corresponding in tbl1.

Trying to get this right with triggers is a **pain**, even without possible concurrent writes.

With possible concurrent writes, it's only even possible with expensive locks (or with [`SERIALIZABLE` snapshot isolation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/transaction-iso.html#XACT-SERIALIZABLE)). You can't have multiple concurrent transactions messing with the max `num` at the same time.

You *could* force all write access on `tbl2` to first take out a row lock on the respective parent row in `tbl1` (and keep track of the current max `tbl2.num` in an additional column `tbl1.max_num` while being at it) ...
See:

- [UPDATE n:m relation in view as array (operations)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/148046/update-nm-relation-in-view-as-array-operations/148128#148128)
- [Delete parent if it's not referenced by any other child](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15810159/939860)

But I wouldn't go there. The safe way to achieve this is to **drop the column `tbl2.pb`** altogether. Instead use a **[`VIEW`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html)** (or [`MATERIALIZED VIEW`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-creatematerializedview.html)) like this to dynamically get the current value, where you need it:

```
CREATE VIEW tbl2_plus_pb AS
SELECT t2.gid, t2.num, t1.pm AS pb, t2.gid_tbl1
FROM  (
   SELECT *, CASE WHEN max(num) OVER (PARTITION BY gid_tbl1) = num
                  THEN gid_tbl1 END AS link
   FROM   tbl2
   ) t2
LEFT   JOIN tbl1 t1 ON t1.gid = t2.link
ORDER  BY t2.gid;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=388cb005921b7b39a41c2c6e07e644d7)*

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation and fiddle. I didn't know it was som complicated. As usual your answer is very useful. Now I have to think about it carefully.