# How to check other table for value during insert

Tags: postgresql, insert, where

In PostgreSQL is it possible to check another table's data to see if there is data that fits a certain condition during an `INSERT` statement?

I have attempted to use `WHERE NOT EXISTS` as I want to not go on with the `INSERT` if I don't find the data I'm looking for in another table but I get the following error:

#### Database Model

[image]

#### Query

```
INSERT INTO car_model(model_name, car_make, date_released)
            VALUES("Classic Car", "Car Brand", "2000-01-01")
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT * FROM car_make
   WHERE company_name = car_make AND date_released >= date_incorperated)
```

Error:

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WHERE"  
> LINE 3: WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM car_make WHERE company_name ...  
>         ^
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work:

```
INSERT INTO car_model(model_name, car_make, date_released)
SELECT *
FROM  (SELECT 'Classic Car', 'Car Brand', '2000-01-01'::date)
  AS i(model_name, car_make, date_released)
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM car_make m
   WHERE  m.company_name = i.car_make
   AND    m.date_incorperated <= i.date_released
   );
```

Or you can still keep the `VALUES` expression to insert multiple rows at once:

```
INSERT INTO car_model(model_name, car_make, date_released)
SELECT *
FROM  (
   VALUES 
   ('Classic Car', 'Car Brand', '2000-01-01'::date)
    -- more rows?
   ) AS i(model_name, car_make, date_released)
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM car_make m
   WHERE  m.company_name = i.car_make
   AND    m.date_incorperated <= i.date_released
   );
```

Note how it may now be necessary to add explicit type casts. See:

- [Casting NULL type when updating multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12427434/939860)

You had a couple of issues:

- A `VALUES` expression does not take a `WHERE` clause. Needs to be a `SELECT` for the purpose.
- Values are enclosed in *single quotes* (`''`). Double quotes (`""`) are for identifiers.
- To refer to input values, you need to form a derived table and attach column aliases first - with a subquery (like I did) or a CTE.

Related:

- [How do I insert a row which contains a foreign key?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46410/how-do-i-insert-a-row-which-contains-a-foreign-key/46477#46477)
- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19364694/939860)