# mysql - insert multiple values sharing same foreign key

Tags: mysql, foreign-key, insert, cte

I have the following tables:

```
create table countries (
    country_id tinyint unsigned,
    iso_alpha3_code varchar(4)
);

create table provinces (
    province_id bigint unsigned,
    province_name varchar(50),
    country_id tinyint unsigned,
    foreign key (country_id) references countries(country_id) on delete restrict on update cascade
);
```

For inserting records into provinces, the corresponding `country_id` is needed:

```
insert into provinces (province_name, country_id) VALUES 
    ('Alabama', (select country_id from countries where iso_alpha3_code = 'USA')), 
    ('California', (select country_id from countries where iso_alpha3_code = 'USA')),
    ('Alaska', (select country_id from countries where iso_alpha3_code = 'USA'));
```

How to insert these records without repeated-select statements to get the foreign key? Can something like [CTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) be used?

**PS:** I found [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/46477/106999), but it's for postgreSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another approach:

```
SELECT @usa := country_id from countries where iso_alpha3_code = 'USA';
insert into provinces (province_name, country_id) 
    VALUES 
    ('Alabama', @usa), 
    ('California', @usa),
    ('Alaska', @usa);
```

But I contend that you should not normalize `country_code`; simply use the standard 3-letter (or 2-letter) codes.

The savings of 2 (or 1) byte is insignificant.  The cost of the `JOIN`, though small, is non-zero.

If you need the table `countries` for other reasons (population, fullname, etc), then let the 3- or 2-character code be the "natural" `PRIMARY KEY` for that table.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
insert into provinces (province_name, country_id) 
SELECT t1.province_name, t2.country_id
FROM ( SELECT 'Alabama' province_name UNION SELECT 'California' UNION SELECT 'Alaska') t1
JOIN (select country_id from countries where iso_alpha3_code = 'USA') t2;
```