# Inserting into multiple tables with a foreign compound key

Tags: postgresql

I have these two table that I would like to insert alot of data into.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS N
(
    id                      INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    name varchar(50)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ConnectionProps
(
    connectionProp  INT,
    FK_n INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY (connectionProp,FK_n),
    CONSTRAINT FK_n
        FOREIGN KEY(id)
            REFERENCES N(id)
                ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

I need to insert into both tables at the same time as the primary key of the `connectionprops` table is a compound key of the foreignkey of N and connectionProps. How do I do this?

Comment: FOREIGN KEY(id), should that be FOREIGN KEY(FK_n)?

Comment: How are you inserting "a lot of data"? If you are going to loop `insert` statements again and again then you are going wrong already. You should use some sort of bulk insert mechanism

Answer (score 4):

Use a CTE and `INSERT ... RETURNING`:

```
WITH x AS (
   INSERT INTO n (name) VALUES ('Willi')
   RETURNING id
)
INSERT INTO connectionprops (connectionprop, fk_n)
SELECT 42, id FROM x;
```

Comment: this approach is flawed, as nobody add two related tables in a mass insert, ass all rows are diffrent

Comment: @nbk What makes you so sure of that?

Comment: It is not flawed at all. The approach can easily be generalized for inserting multiple rows (in both tables) and taking care of the different number of inserts (eg when you insert two connectionProps with the same name). See Erwin's and my answer in this question: [How do I insert a row which contains a foreign key?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46410/how-do-i-insert-a-row-which-contains-a-foreign-key)

Answer (score 1):

You can do following

Where `currval('N_id_seq')`holds the last inserted id.

you had some small errors in your table definitions which i corrected to get a sample

> ```
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS N
> (
>     id                      INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
>     name varchar(50)
> );
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ConnectionProps
> (
>     connectionProp  INT,
>     FK_n INTEGER,
>     PRIMARY KEY (connectionProp,FK_n),
>     CONSTRAINT FK_n1
>         FOREIGN KEY(FK_n)
>             REFERENCES N(id)
>                 ON DELETE CASCADE
> );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> BEGIN;
> INSERT INTO N ("name")  VALUES('test');
> INSERT INTO ConnectionProps (connectionProp,FK_n) VALUES (1,currval('N_id_seq'));
> COMMIT;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

1 rows affected

> 

1 rows affected

> ✓

> ```
> SELECt * FROM ConnectionProps
> ```
>
> ```
> connectionprop | fk_n
> -------------: | ---:
>              1 |    1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=be1634bf2e62d2f8753883d7b1fd1dad)*

Comment: You are making unwarranted assumptions about the name of the sequence.

Comment: currval() only returns a single value so this approach is useless when inserting more than one row.