# ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE command cannot affect row a second time when trying to pass additional columns from a CTE in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key, insert, cte

Based on the SO: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/46477 answer provided, I have been extending the **Function with UPSERT in Postgres 9.5 or later** for my own purposes to insert data into multiple referenced tables.

I have the following `type` that I am passing to the function:

```sql
CREATE TYPE symbol_record AS
(
    name                       character varying(32),
    exchange                   character varying(64),

    base_name                  character varying(16),
    base_precision             smallint,
    base_commission_precision  smallint,
    
    quote_name                 character varying(16),
    quote_precision            smallint,
    quote_commission_precision smallint
);
```

the following relevant CTE's:

```
-- select all the distinct base_name and quote_name
typ_asset AS (SELECT v.name, a.id
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT (base_name) name FROM val
        UNION
        SELECT DISTINCT (quote_name) name FROM val
    ) v
    LEFT JOIN asset a USING (name)
),
```

and

```
ins_asset AS (INSERT INTO asset AS a (name, created_at)
    SELECT name, now()
    FROM typ_asset
    WHERE id IS NULL
    ON CONFLICT (name) DO UPDATE
        SET name = EXCLUDED.name
            WHERE a.name <> EXCLUDED.name
    RETURNING a.name, a.id
),
```

are working correctly.

However, I am unsure how to return the matching 'precision' and 'commission_precision' columns for each of the base/quote for consumption by the calling insert/select in `ins_asset`.

I tried:

```
typ_asset AS (SELECT v.name, v."precision", v.commission_precision, a.id
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT (base_name) name, (base_precision) "precision", (base_commission_precision) commission_precision FROM val
        UNION
        SELECT DISTINCT (quote_name) name, (quote_precision) "precision", (quote_commission_precision) commission_precision FROM val
    ) v
    LEFT JOIN asset a USING (name)
),
```

and adding the columns accordingly to the `ins_asset` CTE, but am getting the error:

**ERROR: ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE command cannot affect row a second time**

I am currently using Postgres 14, and the tables and full function can be seen at:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=bfcb7f7a9a9fcbd8a1b65ec033af8ac2

I am sure it has something to do with the inserting additional data into the `asset` table (typ_asset / ins_asset) ctes, as it works fine without passing the additional columns (or I am passing them back incorrectly)

And further, yes I am fully aware that I am using a reserved keyword (precision). As this is the business language/terminology I have kept it for now (quoting as necessary), but it will also be fixed.

What is the correct way to return the 'precision' and 'commission_precision' columns, and upsert them into the `asset` table?  The 'name' column in the asset table is unique, and I have tried to set commission_precision instead of name in case the unique column was the cause of the error. that also failed with the same error.

**edit**
(1) per requested by *ypercubeᵀᴹ*, the full working fiddle without the precision and commission_precision values in the asset table:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=9f7ad113c6c812c1348bbc85eef24661

(2) I'm sorry, yes you are correct, I have been trying many different things to fix the problem and `DISTINCT ON` was one thing I tried (because I don't fully understand the language), apparently, among several other changes.  I have corrected the non working dbfiddle, and that actually fixed the problem.

Comment: Your linked fiddle uses `SELECT DISTINCT ON ()`. Your query here shows `SELECT DISTINCT`. These are different.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am sorry, I am just learning postgres and am building off examples, I realize (now) parenthesis are used to represent MULTIPLE columns so yes, they are quite 'useless' here, though I left them in more for readability than anything else.  I apologize if that was wrong, but that is the 'why' to your question.  I have fixed the jsfiddle and removed them.

Comment: You shouldn't enclose multiple columns in parentheses either. That will turn those columns into a single column.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name oh, that makes sense too... Thank you for pointing that out. I am learning all of this on the fly (I am a developer, not a dba, and only do the database stuff out of necessity), so your tips on this have clarified a few misconceptions I had as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem like due to the subquery:

```
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT (base_name) name, (base_precision) "precision", (base_commission_precision) commission_precision FROM val
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT (quote_name) name, (quote_precision) "precision", (quote_commission_precision) commission_precision FROM val
) v
```

producing rows with same name but different precision or commission_precision.

You'll need to fix it so it produces only one row for each name - according to your requirements. There may be different cases:

- rows with same base_name but different base_precision/base_commision_precision.
- rows with same quote_name but different quote_precision/quote_commision_precision.
- rows where base_name matches quote_name of other rows (and different precision/commision_precision).

Other points:

- the columns do not need to be in parantheses.
- the following code part looks to be doing totally nothing:

  ```
    ON CONFLICT (name) DO UPDATE
        SET name = EXCLUDED.name
            WHERE a.name <> EXCLUDED.name
  ```

Comment: it was 100% the `DISTINCT ON` vs `DISTINCT` you mentioned in your question comment... I have also removed the additional redundant parenthesis as per @a_horse_with_no_name,

Comment: in my use case, the matching precision/commisson_precision should always be the same for the same asset name (and regardless of whether it is base side or quote side) as far as I can tell (but that may change and may be something I have to deal with in the future for sure)..

Comment: with regards to 'the following code part looks to be doing totally nothing'.. as far as I understand (from the original post I was referring to where I got much of this query/function), the reasoning for that is to prevent race conditions (as it will be called from a multithreaded application), I may be wrong, but that was my understanding of that original post I referenced.